# Raspberry PI + OpenNI2 + OpenCV

Tags: pi-2

I have opencv installed on RPi. Now I need to install OpenNi2
and I have this error:
"error: array subscript is below array bound"

I use: PLATFORM=Arm make

gcc -v 6.3.0

How to solve the problem with above error?

In OpenNI2 README we have
Cross-Compiling for ARM on Linux:
  The following environment variables should be defined:
  - ARM_CXX=
  - ARM_STAGING=
  Then, run:
  $ PLATFORM=Arm make

But I do not know hot to setup

ARM_CXX=

ARM_STAGING=

Answer (score 1):

You could use "sudo apt install libopenni2-0 libopenni2-dev"

This installs the "2.2.0.33+dfsg-7+rpi1 armhf" version of the library.

There are also "openni2-doc" and "openni2-utils".

These seem to be the latest available binaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The installation has passed successfully. Are sample projects also installed with the library? If so, in what catalog can I find examples?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know. They might be in the openni2-utils, or you might have to go to the https://structure.io site and see if they have what you need. I would build the samples on the Raspberry Pi so you don't have to worry about cross-compilation.

Comment: I run without compiling NIViewer example so everything works. I have stream from a camera but when I want to compile SimpleViewer I have the following error
"include<OpenNI.h> not found". I will have to work a bit more on this